# LinkedHashMap order issue

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

It is mentioned in the [LinkedHashMap Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> In particular, operations on collection-views do not affect the order of iteration of the backing map.

What does "operations on collection-views" mean?

Comment: "operations on collection-views" means operations on LInkedHashMap itself. Please cover my [Internal life of LinkedHashMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-linkedhashmap-in-java.html) tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [collection-views of `Map`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) are the objects returned by:

- `Map#keySet()`
- `Map#values()`
- `Map#entrySet()`

Operations on *those* simply means any method calls on the collection-view instance.

Comment: How could any operations on any of those views change iteration order, since you can't add or get?

Comment: @assylias I'm not sure; theoretically iterating over the collection views?

Comment: LinkedHashMap has a constructor that orders elements by most recent access, so its perfectly conceivable that contains or other lookup operations on collection views might affect iteration order in that case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the same paragraph explicitly lists the methods that generate an access: get, put and putAll. And none of the views has any of these methods so it seems redundant. But admittedly it is not wrong so not a big deal.

Answer (score 7):

This test is supposed to demonstrate how it works

```
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap(16, 0.75f, true);
    m.put(1, 1);
    m.put(2, 2);
    m.put(3, 3);
    System.out.println(m);
    m.get(2);
    System.out.println(m);
    Set keys = m.keySet(); //API: Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map.
    keys.iterator().next();
    System.out.println(m);
```

output

```
{1=1, 2=2, 3=3}
{1=1, 3=3, 2=2}
{1=1, 3=3, 2=2}
```

that is, accessing entry 2-2 changed the iteration order, and accessing the first entry 1-1 on the keySet view did not

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, maybe I don't, the collection-view are the `Collection`s obtained by its  abstractions, like entrySet, values and keySet.

Operations in these sets will not affect the order of access of the objects inside yours `LinkedHashMap` when you're using the special constructor that makes your objects be order by access-order.